# Twython: Error running the examples

Tags: python, twitter, twython

Hi i have just started to evaluate different options for python>Twitter api:s.

I have written some code looking at the examples in the Twython package but i always end up getting the same error.

```
AttributeError: 'Twython' object has no attribute 'auth'
```

I also get the same error running the included core_example files.

I am running "2.0.0" from git.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python /Users/skjortan/dev/trunk/3rdPartyLibs/twython/core_examples/current_trends.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/skjortan/dev/trunk/3rdPartyLibs/twython/core_examples/current_trends.py", line 5, in <module>
    trends = twitter.getCurrentTrends()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twython-2.0.0-py2.7.egg/twython/twython.py", line 167, in <lambda>
    return lambda **kwargs: self._constructFunc(key, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twython-2.0.0-py2.7.egg/twython/twython.py", line 188, in _constructFunc
    content = self._request(url, method=method, params=kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twython-2.0.0-py2.7.egg/twython/twython.py", line 205, in _request
    response = func(url, data=myargs, auth=self.auth)
AttributeError: 'Twython' object has no attribute 'auth'
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed your question - I'm the author of Twython. A fix has been committed and pushed out for a 2.0.1 release. If you update your installation this should no longer be an issue.

Thanks, sorry for the hassle! Bug that slipped by our 2.0.0 release.

Answer (score 0):

But its really has no attribute 'auth' but it has methods like:

```
def get_authentication_tokens(self):
    """Returns an authorization URL for a user to hit."""

def get_authorized_tokens(self):
    """Returns authorized tokens after they go through the auth_url phase."""
```

And this is sample from django-twython how its author make auth

```
def begin_auth(request):
    """
    The view function that initiates the entire handshake.
    For the most part, this is 100% drag and drop.
    """
    # Instantiate Twython with the first leg of our trip.
    twitter = Twython(
    twitter_token = settings.TWITTER_KEY,
    twitter_secret = settings.TWITTER_SECRET,
    callback_url =     request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('twython_django_oauth.views.thanks')))

    # Request an authorization url to send the user to...
    auth_props = twitter.get_authentication_tokens()

    # Then send them over there, durh.
    request.session['request_token'] = auth_props
    return HttpResponseRedirect(auth_props['auth_url'])
```

Answer (score 0):

apparently twitter api and does not allow normal login, just for oauth, creates the application on Twitter and OAuth Settings tab from there takes the data from OAuth Settings, and methods of oauth in:

http://pydoc.net/twython/1.4.5/twython.twitter_endpoints

Comment: But basic search and get public timeline should not require auth. Or has that changed in the twitter api lately?